# Passing return value of try catch to another activity

Tags: android, tcpclient

I am new in android programming, I am trying to receive packet data via TCP client on android.

After I get the streaming packet from raspberry pi, the packet will be parsed into variables, in my Masukan() function that returns **string** value named **filter**.

I can get the returned value of Masukan() on my Adhrs Activity , but I cannot get the returned value from Masukan() that accessed from another activity.

The error says Nullpointerexception, I would appreciate any help with the same.
This is my code :

```
 package com.uavgama;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.UnknownHostException;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 public class Adhrsparse extends Activity {
 String[] parsing = null;
 private final String server = "192.168.43.20";

 Handler handler = new Handler();
 Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
 Keluar();

 }
 };

 //declaration of textview etc

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.adahrs);
 status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);
 paketdata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView17);

 tvalt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView18);
 tvasp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView19);
 tvlat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView20);
 tvlon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView21);
 tvptc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);
 tvrol = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView23);
 tvyaw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView24);

 Keluar();

 }

 public String Keluar(){

  String masuk = new String();
  try {
  masuk = Masukan();
  status.setText(masuk);
  } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  //    Intent intentcam = new Intent(this,CameraView.class);
  //    intentcam.putExtra("filter", filter);
  //    startActivity(intentcam);
  e.printStackTrace();
  }

  handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
  return masuk;
  }

  public String Masukan() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{

  Socket s = new Socket(server,12345);
  //BufferedReader inp = null;
  BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
  //String serverMsg = null;
  String serverMsg = inp.readLine();
  //filter keutuhan data kemudian diprint di var paketdata
  if ( serverMsg.endsWith("#")) {
  filter = serverMsg; 
  }
  paketdata.setText(filter);
  parsing = filter.split("\\|");

  parsing[0] = parsing[0].replace("$", "");
  tvalt.setText(parsing[0]);
  tvasp.setText(parsing[1]);
  tvlat.setText(parsing[2]);
  tvlon.setText(parsing[3]);
  tvptc.setText(parsing[4]);
  tvrol.setText(parsing[5]);
  parsing[6] = parsing[6].replace("#", "");
  tvyaw.setText(parsing[6]);

  s.close();

return filter; 

  };

  }
```

and my another activity

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.uavgama.Adhrsparse;

public class CameraView extends Activity{
String[] parsingcam = null;
private final String server = "192.168.43.20";
InetAddress


   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() {
        adhrspars();

 }
  };

TextView statuse;
TextView paketdata;
TextView data;
String latlon;
String filter;
String parse;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);
      runnable.run();
    Intent fltr = getIntent();
    latlon = fltr.getStringExtra("filter");
    data.setText(latlon);


    adhrspars();
          adhrs();


}


public void adhrspars(){
adhrs();


}

public void adhrs() {
String parsed = new String();
    Adhrsparse adhrs = new Adhrsparse();
    try {
        parsed = adhrs.Masukan() ;
        data.setText(parsed);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);


    };
```

Here is my logcat :

```
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.uavgama/com.uavgama.CameraView}:      java.lang.NullPointerException
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2063)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1904)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:753)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:417)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:158)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4103)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17117)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4744)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at com.uavgama.CameraView.onCreate(CameraView.java:48)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2027)
 07-23 20:00:14.708: E/AndroidRuntime(24895):   ... 18 more
```

Thank You for your helps

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to send the data? Also, post your logcat

Comment: Im trying send data to another class named cameraview , this my logcat :
07-23 19:21:45.134: E/AndroidRuntime(20942): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 19:21:45.134: E/AndroidRuntime(20942): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.uavgama/com.uavgama.CameraView}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Post your full logcat in your question

Comment: Post the logcat so we can see what is `null`. Also, unless there is a reason that method has to be in that `Activity` you could move it to a separate class since it is shared by multiple `Activities`

Comment: Where are you starting your camera activity?

Comment: See my answer. You aren't initializing your `TextView`

Comment: In my app, i use frame tab , at first will show adhrs activity, and the data stream is showed on textview normaly,but when i click my cameraview tab, the app closed.

Comment: The second part of my answer will solve your `NPE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple issues. First, if you aren't sending data through the `Intent` with

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("key", value);   // this line here adds the extra data
```

then `latlon` will be `null` but not necessarily throw a `NPE`.

Second, and I believe this is where you are getting your `NPE`, you never initialize your `TextView data` so you get a `NPE` when you try to call `setText()` on it. Change your `onCreate()` to something like

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera);
      runnable.run();
    Intent fltr = getIntent();
    latlon = fltr.getStringExtra("filter");

    data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idOfTextView);   // YOU NEED TO INITAILIZE IT LIKE THIS

    data.setText(latlon);
```

Since your `Masukan()` method is used in multiple places, you may want to take out the parts that get the data and put them in a `static` method in a separate Java class then when you want that `String` just run

```
   String variableName = SomeClassName.Masukan();
```

from wherever you are

Comment: ohh i see,im sorry my mistakes. When im use intent to get return value of Masukan(), where i should place that code?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The code to get the value would be fine where it is if you are using `putExtra()` when you create the `Intent` to start the `CameraView` `Activity`

Comment: i mean where i must placed that intent code, in oncreate method or some where, im sory my english is bad, but that is no matter, I've make another class that inside it i put my masukan() method, and call that method like you said before, and it works !Thankyou !:D i can call Masukan() method on every activity, but the delay is quite slower than before,i want the data transfer have low latency below 100 ms , so what should i do ? reduce the delay on runnable ?

Comment: You could do that but I'm not sure why you have a `runnable` anyway. If it is getting data from the network then I would suggest `AsyncTask`. I'm glad its working but as far as where to place the `Intent` code, that just depends on where you need it but generally `onCreate()` is a good place for it

Comment: Ohh i see now, at first the streaming data is come one by one packet,so i think just refresh it use runnable delay. thats come from hehe
Okay i'll try your suggestion,,but when im get the streaming data,sometimes it jammed from logcat says Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused) , what i supposed to do? My streaming data comes from Arduino that i set send packet every 100ms (but i get the data higher than 100ms delay)that connected to Raspberry pi wifi network that i access

Comment: I haven't worked with that so I'm not sure and that's a completely separate issue. You should accept this answer by clicking the checkmark since we got you going and you can post a new question regarding that with the relevant code and logcat.

Comment: Okey thank you very much @codeMagic , your answer is awesome and fit work on my app problems . Thanks :)